# Why is socket behaviour dependant on a print statement?

Tags: python, sockets, printing

I do not understand how something like a print statement can affect socket behaviour. The following code was run on windows, from idle and cmd.

server.py:

```py
from types import SimpleNamespace
import socket
import selectors

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65433

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
server_sock.listen()
print('Server listening on', (HOST, PORT))

server_sock.setblocking(False)
sel.register(server_sock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)

def accept_new_connection(server_sock):
    connected_sock, addr = server_sock.accept()
    connected_sock.setblocking(False)

    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
    data = SimpleNamespace(addr = addr, outb = b'', inb = b'')
    sel.register(connected_sock, events, data=data)

    print('new connection', addr, 'accepted')

def service_connection(key, event):
    connected_sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data

    if event & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = connected_sock.recv(1024)
        if data:
            data.outb += recv_data
        else:
            print('closing the connection', data.addr)
            sel.unregister(connected_sock)
            connected_sock.close()

    elif event & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if data.outb:
            print('echoing', data.outb, 'to', data.addr)
            sent = connected_sock.send(data.outb)
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]
            print('ANYTHING') # removing this changes socket behaviour
        else:
            # this executes if print('ANYTHING') is not present
            print('nothing to send') 

while True:
    events = sel.select(timeout=None)
    for key, event in events:
        if key.data == None:
            accept_new_connection(key.fileobj)
        else:
            service_connection(key, event)
```

client.py:

```py
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65433

ls = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ls.connect((HOST, PORT))
ls.send(b'Hi world')
ls.recv(1024)
ls.close()
```

Running those two programs (first server, then client) 
producess different results, depending on whether 
`print('ANYTHING')` is present.

When run with the `print('ANYTHING')` included, 
I get

```
Server listening on ('127.0.0.1', 65433)
new connection ('127.0.0.1', 58675) accepted
echoing b'Hi world' to ('127.0.0.1', 58675)
ANYTHING
```

and without it

```
Server listening on ('127.0.0.1', 65433)
new connection ('127.0.0.1', 58678) accepted
echoing b'Hi world' to ('127.0.0.1', 58678)
nothing to send
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change the indentation of `else:` when you added/removed the `print` statement?

Comment: I checked it very carefully again and yes, the result was the same.

Comment: The extra `print` statement can change timing of asynchronous events.

Comment: swap out the print with time.sleep(1). If that behaves the same as the print statement: it's a race condition and you need to handle that with checks.

Comment: @Barmar Ok that would explain the behaviour. Do you know of any sources, where this kind of events are explained well?

Comment: @JacobIRR Yeah this behaves the same as print. What do you mean by checks?

Comment: Steffen Ullrich has a good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
...
sel.register(connected_sock, events, data=data)
```

This makes select trigger whenever the socket is writable - no matter if you actually have something to write in `data.outb` or not. Which means it will trigger always as long the socket is not closed yet.

```
ls.connect((HOST, PORT))
ls.send(b'Hi world')
```

This will connect to the server. The connection will be done inside the OS kernel and will ultimately result in triggering the server socket in your program which then calls `accept`. But `connect` actually returns in the client after the connection is established in the servers kernel, which might be before `accept` was called. The `send` thus will provide the newly created socket already with data.

```
def service_connection(key, event):
    ...
    if event & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        ...
    elif event & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        ...
```

Your server handles only a single condition at the socket, even if the socket is both readable and writeable. It is always writable as explained above but you run into the readable first since the data from the client are already in the socket buffer at the server side once you've finished `accept`. Thus, the first `EVENT_WRITE` will only be handled once there are already data in `data.outb` from the previous `EVENT_READ`.

```
        sent = connected_sock.send(data.outb)
        data.outb = data.outb[sent:]
        print('ANYTHING') # removing this changes socket behaviour
```

This send the data to the client and then adds some delay to the server since printing to the terminal actually takes some time. If this delay is not there (i.e. no `print`) then the selector will immediately be called again (since `EVENT_WRITE` always triggers, see above) and your code will stumble over the empty `data.outb`.

If this delay is there though then the socket will be closed (and thus no more `EVENT_WRITE` triggered) since the client closes the connection immediately after it received the data:

```
ls.recv(1024)
ls.close()
```

Note that this only behaves this way since you are using client and server on the same machine. If these would be on different machines then network latency would add enough timing differences by their own so you might see a different but maybe similar confusing behavior.

The proper way to handle this situation is of course to enable `EVENT_WRITE` only if you actually have data in `data.outb` and disable it immediately if all data are sent.